# Operation not allowed while using iframe to play vimeo embed video in android

Tags: android, iframe, video, webview, vimeo

I used a webView to play vimeo embed video. My webview works fine while playing youtube videos. But when I load vimeo video the thumbnail is shown in webview but when I click play button, a toast with message :**Operation not allowed** is displayed. Then whole screen goes grey with video icon in center.

Here is my webView code:

```
<WebView
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:id="@+id/webViewYoutube"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And my fragment code to load video in webView.

```
 String vimeoFrame="<html><body><iframe src=\"http://player.vimeo.com/video/113067409?autoplay=1&loop=1\" width=\"300\" height=\"200\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></body></html>";
    WebView vimeoPlayer = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webViewYoutube);
    WebSettings webSettings2 = vimeoPlayer.getSettings();
    webSettings2.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings2.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webSettings2.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings2.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings2.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    vimeoPlayer.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    vimeoPlayer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    vimeoPlayer.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);

    vimeoPlayer.loadData(vimeoFrame, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

**UPDATE**
Looking deep in Logcat, I discovered warning stacktrace which is like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://s.vimeocdn.com/vimeo-prod-std-us/video/393408632.mp4?token=55afa9c1_0x34d715bffb7e3c81b0c424ee5a62862913e2c1e6
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:710)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:614)
        at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:985)
        at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataCommon(HTML5VideoView.java:309)
        at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoView.java:346)
        at android.webkit.HTML5VideoInline.prepareDataAndDisplayMode(HTML5VideoInline.java:57)
        at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:265)
        at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:416)
```

It appears that parsing of Embed Vimeo video url was not properly done by android. I tested same embed url with iOS which works fine. This issue is only with Android. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: the error  indicates that url contains expires token so please regenerate url again and check it is because of expires url